# How to change text to bold when font does not support bold

Tags: fonts, color, bold, indic

I have a 100 page document, I used colored text many places to highlight with below command in my preamble

```
\newcommand\bluetext[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
```

its working great however did not realize at the time of writing that i would require color printer for this. I wanted to change colored text to bold - I change the above command as below

```
 \newcommand\bluetext[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

It removed the colors but did not give me any bold letters, is it because of the font? or I am doing anything wrong? I am using sanskrit 2003 font. 
[image: Bold_image]

In the attached image all the circled text should have appeared bold. 
Thanks for your help - Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[24pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amstext, amsmath}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit2003}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\newcommand\bluetext[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} 
%\newcommand\bluetext[1]{\textbf{#1}} % Blue Text
\begin{document}
१.१.१\bluetext{वृद्धिः}\textsuperscript{१/१} आत्\textsuperscript{१/१} ऐच्\textsuperscript{१/१}     \\
१.१.२     अत्\textsuperscript{१/१}  एङ्\textsuperscript{१/१} गुणः\textsuperscript{१/१}     \\
१.१.३     \bluetext{इकः}\textsuperscript{६/१} \bluetext{गुणवृद्धी}\textsuperscript{१/२}    \\
 १.१.४     \bluetext{न}\textsuperscript{०/०} धातुलोपे\textsuperscript{७/१} आर्धधातुके\textsuperscript{७/१}    \\
१.१.५     क्क्ङिति\textsuperscript{७/१} च\textsuperscript{०/०}     \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: You didn't give enough informations to decide if you did something wrong or if your font simply doesn't offer a bold version. Add a small but complete example that shows how you call and use the font.

Comment: This is what I have in the preamble \setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit2003} and wherever is need I just type in this font. I am using Xelatex

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use this font, `fontspec` will tell you in the log-file:

```
Could not resolve font Sanskrit 2003/B (it probably doesn't exist).
```

This means that the font has no bold (/B) version.

You can use the AutoFakeBold key to get a faked bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,AutoFakeBold=3.5]{Sanskrit 2003}
\begin{document}
test ^^^^e081

\bfseries
test ^^^^e081

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Fischer - Thanks for your help, it worked and it also solved many problems for me because there are other works where I needed to bold but did not realize why its not giving bold output.

Comment: could you please tell me what to change for a Persian font?

Comment: @Gigili: Simply change the font name and perhaps the script. But first check if you font has a real bold font -- AutoFakeBold should be only your second choice.